# Getting Number of Elements of Dataframe equal to elements in List - R

Tags: r, comparison

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
DataFrame$Fruit
Apple
Banana
Apple
Mango
Banana
```

etc

I would like to use the data (for instance count the numbers, but also do other manipulations), for which the Fruits are the same in some given array:

`keepFruit = c('Apple', 'Banana')`

The following expression: `Dataframe$Fruit[which(Dataframe$Fruit == 'Apple' | Dataframe$Fruit == 'Banana')]` returns the correct number of elements, however the following expression gives an erroneous number: `Dataframe$Fruit[which(Dataframe$Fruit == keepFruit)]`

I understand the second expression is comparing an array to a single text entry, however how come it still returns somewhat correct results (returns elements where the fruits match up) though not the same number (i.e. not all)? And what is a better way to get the data for all fruits that are members of the `keepFruit` array?

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for exactly that. Would you know what the == was actually comparing in the case of an array?

Comment: R will recycle shorter vectors until they are the same length as the longer one. See `help("==")`.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind submitting this as an answer so I may accept it?

Comment: @msmf14 I was in the process of doing just that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `%in%` for this, not `==`. Here's an example:

```
df <- data.frame(Fruit = c("Apple","Banana","Apple","Mango","Banana"))
keepFruit = c('Apple', 'Banana')

ind <- with(df, Fruit %in% keepFruit)
df[ind, , drop = FALSE]
```

Giving

```
> df[ind, , drop = FALSE]
   Fruit
1  Apple
2 Banana
3  Apple
5 Banana
```

As for why `==` doesn't work, you must appreciate that `==` does an *element-wise* comparison of `Fruit` and `keepFruit`, i.e. it compare the first elements of each vector for equality, then the second elements of each vector, and so on. Now `keepFruit` is not of the same length as `Fruit`, so R *recycles* the elements of `keepFruit` to match the length of `Fruit`, the longer of the two vectors. It is as if R has done

```
with(df, Fruit == rep(keepFruit, length = length(Fruit)))
```

or

```
keepFruit2 <- with(df, rep(keepFruit, length = length(Fruit)))
with(df, Fruit == keepFruit2)
rm(keepFruit2)
```

both return (which is not what you wanted but is correct as far as R's rules go)

```
> with(df, Fruit == rep(keepFruit, length = length(Fruit)))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

R does a little bit more than this however, because it warns you that the length of the longer vector `Fruit` is not a multiple of the length of the shorter vector `keepFruit` - this almost always indicates a problem, hence the warning:

```
> with(df, Fruit == keepFruit)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(Fruit, keepFruit) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

To see in more detail what happens, we can augment `df` with the values used in the comparison with `==` and the result

```
df2 <- within(df, {
    Keep <- rep(keepFruit, length = length(Fruit))
    Result <- Fruit == Keep
  })
df2

> df2
   Fruit Result   Keep
1  Apple   TRUE  Apple
2 Banana   TRUE Banana
3  Apple   TRUE  Apple
4  Mango  FALSE Banana
5 Banana  FALSE  Apple
```

Now you should be able to see why you got the result you did with `==` and why it was wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough and helpful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also `Vectorize`

```
Vectorize(function(x) df$Fruit==x)(keepFruit) #which gives the logical index of matching positions
     Apple Banana
#[1,]  TRUE  FALSE
#[2,] FALSE   TRUE
#[3,]  TRUE  FALSE
#[4,] FALSE  FALSE
#[5,] FALSE   TRUE
```